# Create multiband raster from .las file using PDAL

Tags: python, raster, classification, point-cloud, pdal

I am quite new to creating rasters from point cloud (.las) files. Basically, I would like to use **PDAL** and its `writers.gdal` stage to write a raster with two bands.
**The first band** should be written using the dimension set to `Classification` in order to make the raster cell gets the value of the **highest Classification point index** within that cell (which I have already achieved):

```
{
                    "type": "writers.gdal",
                    "filename": str(output_raster_path),
                    "gdaldriver": "GTiff",
                    "gdalopts": "-a_srs EPSG:7856",
                    "dimension": "Classification",
                    "output_type": "max",
                    "resolution": res,
                    "data_type": "float32"
}
```

For **the second band**, I want PDAL to write the **corresponding z-values** of the extracted points in **band 1**.

What I do not want to achieve is creating a second `writers.gdal` stage with the dimension set to `Z` because that would result in PDAL looking for the max value of classification indices for band 1 and the max value of z-values for band 2. Instead, band 2 should just contain the z-values of the corresponding points which are written into band 1 using the classification dimension and `"output_type":"max"`.
If this desired output is not possible to achieve with PDAL, I would be happy for some good alternative approaches. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this by writing a single file in PDAL, but you can do it in a single pipeline. You'll need to write two files out and then merge them together. The following example pipeline uses the [Autzen test file](https://viewer.copc.io?state=f4ac76d5f227f46867cf965cacddbfb2d536333391d555dc7ddf0a84a75d5e89) that is commonly used in PDAL examples:

```
[
    {
        "type": "readers.copc",
        "tag": "reader",
        "filename": "/Users/hobu/dev/git/pdal-data/autzen/autzen-classified.copc.laz",
        "resolution": 1.0
    },
    {
        "type": "writers.gdal",
        "tag": "hag_writer",
        "filename": "classification.tif",
        "resolution": 2.0,
        "output_type": "max",
        // binmode means only accumulate statistics for points *inside* the pixel
        "binmode": "true",
        "dimension": "Classification",
        "data_type": "float32"
    },
    {
        "type": "writers.gdal",
        "tag": "dtm_writer",
        "filename": "z.tif",
        "resolution": 2.0,
        "output_type": "idw",
        "data_type": "float32"
    },
    {
        "type": "filters.shell",
        "command": "gdalbuildvrt -separate stack.vrt classification.tif z.tif"
    },
    {
        "type": "filters.shell",
        "command": "gdal_translate stack.vrt final.tif"
    },
    // clean up temporaries
    {
        "type": "filters.shell",
        "command": "rm stack.vrt classification.tif z.tif"
    }
]
```

If you set the `PDAL_ALLOW_SHELL=1` variable, you can use `filters.shell` of PDAL to inline the GDAL commands into the same pipeline. This is a security hole if you were doing it on a web server or something like that, however.

```
PDAL_ALLOW_SHELL=1 pdal pipeline highest-z.json
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggested approach! But does that really ensure, that the file "z.tif" contains exactly the z-values of the corresponding points written to "classification.tif"? As far as I know, using the output_type "idw" for writing the "z.tif" would result in writing the z-values with the Shepard's Inverse Distance Weighting Algorithm while we aggregate the classification points in "classification.tif" with the max function.

Comment: You could use `binmode` for writing the Z raster (note the resolutions must be the same or the rasters wont line up). It might be easier to control exactly what you want by doing this in Python/Numpy, however.